# How to change different format of text into one format in c#

Tags: c#, linq, format-conversion

I ask the question on the context of anology lets say i have diiferent forms of dates and i want to convert them in one format. I did that by using below code

```
string[] dates =
                          {
                "december-21-2016",
                "december, 28,2016",
                "27 january,2017",
                "29 december,2016",
                "03 mar 1990"

                            };
        string[] formattedDates = new string[dates.Length];

        string[] formats = { "MMMM-dd-yyyy","MMMM, dd,yyyy","MMMM, d,yyyy","dd MMMM,yyyy","dd MMM yyyy" };
        for (int i = 0; i < dates.Length; i++)
        {
            DateTime date;
            if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dates[i], formats, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out date))
                formattedDates[i] = date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
            Console.WriteLine(formattedDates[i]);
        }
```

here is the output
21-12-2016, 
 28-12-2016,
 27-01-2017,
 29-12-2016,
 03-03-1990,

I want to write the same code but for text instead of dates like

```
string[] formats=
           {
            "Husband and Wife",
            "Wife and Husband",
            "Husband and Wife",
            "Wife and Husband",
            "hus & wife",
            "H & W",               
            };
```

but the output should be "H and W", for all format above there.
It will be more awesome if we can do this using linq.

sorry for bad english & formatting, i m new to this.

Comment: It should be possible, but it has nothing to do with `DateTime` parsing.

Comment: Just follow the same logic as your datetime code.  Loop through `formats` and check each string for the words *husband* and *wife* and then add "H and W" to your output.

Comment: Does "Hard Worker" satisfy your requirement - if not - why? Please remove unrelated and impossible-to-get-right date parsing sample and instead define clear rules and code you tried to solve the problem already.

Answer (score 0):

While `DateTime` has somewhat an easy way to parse them based on format, other text forms might be more difficult to deal with.

I am not sure Regex is the best suited in such scenario, however, you can inspire yourself from the code below in order to achieve your text parsing:

```
public class RegexTextCalibrator
{
    private ICollection<Tuple<Regex, string>> Calibrations = new List<Tuple<Regex, string>>();

    public void AddParallelPattern(IEnumerable<string> a, IEnumerable<string> b, string output)
    {
        this.AddParallelPattern(a, b, @"\W+.*", output);
    }

    public void AddParallelPattern(IEnumerable<string> a, IEnumerable<string> b, string inBetweenLinkPattern, string output)
    {
        string subPatternA = String.Join("|", a);
        string subPatternB = String.Join("|", b);

        var patternA = String.Format("({0})({1})({2})", subPatternA, inBetweenLinkPattern, subPatternB);
        var patternB = String.Format("({0})({1})({2})", subPatternB, inBetweenLinkPattern, subPatternA);

        this.Add(String.Format("{0}|{1}", patternA, patternB), output);
    }

    public void Add(string pattern, string output)
    {
        this.Add(new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase), output);
    }

    public void Add(Regex regex, string output)
    {
        Calibrations.Add(new Tuple<Regex, string>(regex, output));
    }

    public string Resolve(string value)
    {
        var calibration = this.Calibrations.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Item1.IsMatch(value));
        return calibration != null ? calibration.Item2 : null;
    }
}
```

**Edit** Below is the commented use of the above code.

You can use the class as follow:

```
// configure the calibration/mapping.
var calibrator = new RegexTextCalibrator();
calibrator.AddParallelPattern(
                new[] { "husband", "hus", "h" }, // defines one side of the pattern
                new[] { "wife", "w" }, // defines the other side of the pattern
                "H and W"); // defines the result

// the inputs that will be mapped
var inputs = new string[] {
    "Husband and Wife",
    "Wife and Husband",
    "Husband and Wife",
    "Wife and Husband",
    "hus & wife",
    "H & W"
};

// loops through the inputs and map them to the desired value
foreach (var input in inputs)
    Console.WriteLine(calibrator.Resolve(input)); // prints "H and W"...
```

Comment: Thanks for ur help man but its not what i want maybe i didn't understand it. My requirement is that i have these inputs : "hus & wife", "wife & hus", "Husband and Wife", "H & W". i want this output for all of inputs "H and W".

Comment: @user3882060 If I understood well, the edit should show you how to use this method.